# How to update programs built from source

Tags: linux, makefile, archlinux

can you tell me how to update programs installed with "sudo make install".
I'm asking if i have to uninstall the program and then redo "./autogen.sh" "make" "sudo make install".Someone say that I need to remove the program and then build it again after git pull, others say that i can simply reinstall it using the updated source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends. If it simply minor update, just go for recompilation and `make install`.

If any changes in supplied libs and/or header files were done (e.g. they were renamed), you better uninstall software first to get rid of unneeded files on your filesystem.

Comment: OOk thank you. So i have to check the changes everytime to decide ?

Comment: @Fabiuz99 you're making it complicated; just `make install` newer version; if you've got any issues, `make uninstall` and reinstall it.

Comment: It's because I use a script to update my programs installed with git and I didn't now if include simply make install or remove the programs and install them again. From your answer I have understood that the second option is better

Answer (score 1):

It's *really* difficult to uninstall a program that you've installed yourself in a default location. If you're very lucky, there will be an `uninstall` or `deinstall` target for `make`, but most of the time there isn't. It's probably a matter of manually hunting down the files and removing them, unless you reinstall the same version of the code again and somehow keep an eye of where things are actually ending up (which would only make the "hunting down" bit marginally easier)

**In the future, you may choose to do things differently:**
Most source distribution that uses a GNU `configure` script allows you to specify a *prefix* for the installation using `--prefix=path`. This allows you to make the install in a separate sub-directory, which then would be simple to delete.

For example, let's say I'm installing a fictional piece of software called ThePackage, version 14.4:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/stow/thepackage-14.4
$ make && sudo make install
```

(I usually use a path under `$HOME/local/stow`)

Notice the `stow` in there? No coincidence that there is a neat utility called precisely this, [available from the GNU people](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/).

After having installed the software as above, under `.../stow/thepackage-14.4`, it's simply a matter of

```
$ cd /usr/local/stow
$ sudo stow -v thepackage-14.4
```

This populates `/usr/local` with symbolic links so that, for example, any executable in `/usr/local/stow/thepackage-14.4/bin` is available in `/usr/local/bin` (etc.)

To uninstall:

```
$ cd /usr/local/stow
$ sudo stow -D -v thepackage-14.4
$ sudo rm -rf thepackage-14.4
```

This even allows you to have several versions of some software installed under `/usr/local/stow`.  To "activate" one particular version, just `stow -D` whatever version you were using and `stow` the one you'd like to test out. If the new version it wasn't performing to your requirements, reverse the actions.

Other build systems can also be made to install under a separate prefix. For example, to make CMake install as above, use

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/stow/thepackage-14.4
$ make && sudo make install
```

You can also use `stow` with Perl packages, and whatever else installs in a customizable path.

Answer (score 0):

There is (usually) no `make uninstall`.

This is why I always install such software into a separate directory, named after the software and its version number.  For instance, when installing GNU Make 4.1 from source I will install it into a directory `make-4.1`.

Then I symlink all of the relevant files into a common directory tree that I use in my `$PATH`, `$MANPATH`, etcetera.  I use my own script for doing that, but that is only because I didn't know about [`stow`](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) when I wrote it.

This allows me to install multiple versions side by side and pick the "current" one by removing and adding the symlinks in question with my script.  I can uninstall software simply by removing its directory tree.

This also works for software with dependencies that also need to be installed in this way.  The hardest part is in deciding whether to make a dependency version-specific or not.